# PHP modify image

Tags: php

I want to modify image before uploading it.

By modifing I mean bluring it I have Php 5.3.27. Can you suggested anything which does not involve installing any additional modules (since I'm on shared hosting)

I find this http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php but I'm not sure if recource can be `$_FILES['file']`

Comment: why not modify the image after upload and save it instead of modifying every time? Performance is affected, and you will make the user wait every page load for the image modification. Its also not logical to modify it every time

Comment: you have your point, I though it would be easier, then modifying my existing function for upload (then I will have to save both, blured and unblured image) but while searching I think you are right. 

I'll modify my question

Comment: Good suggestion @zgr024. One less IO means faster performance as there are more elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, you can have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php -- Many hoster are having gd installed, but not all. So you have to check this.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked and it is supported.
I just updated my question, which do you suggested [imagefilter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php) or the GD one?

Comment: okay they are same )) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS3 filters](http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/css-filters/). They are relatively easy to implement, though are only supported on webkit at the minute.

Comment: I know, but thats not what I'm looking. I have a performance problems with it. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472217/dont-repaint-background-while-scrolling